# Computing persistent homology using clique complex filtrations

Tags: homology-cohomology, computational-mathematics

In 

[this](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/research/imag/courses/Vaccarino/homology%20complex%20network.pdf) paper, the authors compute the persistent homology (and barcode) of a random (Erdos-Renyi) network.

For their filtration, they start with the clique complex of the graph, which is the simplicial complex with an n-simplex for each (n+1)-clique present in the graph, and consider the *ith* skeleton of this for the *ith* step in the filtration.

I can not work out how you would programme this filtration as a Vietoris-Rips complex, for example. If we embed a graph in a metric space, and say that nodes are distance 1 apart if they are connected in the graph, and some higher distance apart otherwise, then a Vietoris-Rips complex would immediately give you the full clique complex, and I am unsure whether you can make it give you the *i* skeletons in turn.

I thought about trying to programme it as a Cech complex, but I do not believe Javaplex, which seems to be the most common software in this area, can do Cech complexes.